# including remote files in c#

Tags: c#, namespaces, remote-file-inclusion

I have c# file with all contents contained in a **namespace LinkedList** saved with the name **linkedlist.cs** . This file doesn't have a main() method. I want to include the content of that file or that namespace in another file.

How can I do that ?

Comment: Another file in the same project? or are you trying to add it to another project? Perhaps reading [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/z2kcy19k.aspx) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) will be of some help

Comment: Add it to a project, and in the other file add `using LinkedList;`?

Comment: what kind of content u have ? under a name space you can only host classes, enumerations, delegates interfaces and struct. if your content is a class you should instantiate it unless it is static.and in all cases you have to follow what cdhowie said.

Comment: thanks for this help, but if I wanted to do the same in linux (without any ide) using dmcs compiler? How can do that?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `LinkedList` is in a project called `MyLinkedListProject`, you will want to reference this project from the project inheriting it. As stated in the comments by @cdhowie you can then reference the namespace by adding the `using LinkedList;` which will reference the namespace.

Depending on the content of linkedlist.cs will depend on how you access it, assuming it contains a class called `LinkedList` within the `LinkedList` you would access the methods (of the `class` using code such as `LinkedList.methodName();` (this would work for a `static` method, you'd have to instantiate a `LinkedList` first if you require an "instance of the object" for the method to work.